# Selenium Webdriver doesnt find ALL elements on website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, instagram

I ve been working on an Instagram automation program but there's one problem:
When i try to find all LIKE buttons and print them

it only likes the first 4 pictures but there are many more and i dont know why it cant find them

Using Selenium, Python, Selenium Webdriver, time, Keys(from selenium)
Code:

```
hearts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, '_eszkz
_l9yih')]")

for i, heart in enumerate(hearts):
    print('{}/{}'.format(i, len(hearts)))
    heart.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: what _HTML_ ???

Comment: The HTML relevant to the question... how can we check your locator if we can't see the HTML?

Comment: go to istagram, login and go to your news feed -> thats the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Its only due  the way instagram loads the pages items

Instagram only load 4 pictures at time

Will need to scroll down the page to load more

```
hearts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, '_eszkz _l9yih')]")

while True: #infinite loop
    q = len(hearts)
    last_item = hearts[q-1]
    for i, heart in enumerate(hearts):
        print('{}/{}'.format(i, len(hearts)))
    #heart.click()
    sleep(2)
    last_item.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    hearts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, '_eszkz _l9yih')]")
```

Get the last item list, and scroll to it and reload the list

[Here the full code](https://github.com/guilhermebferreira/selenium-notebooks/blob/master/Infinite%20Loop%20on%20Instagram.ipynb)

Comment: but i included a code where it loads more pictures and this while True loop doesnt work for me

Comment: The while was just for a example

Comment: @BoratTV my answer was to explain why u get only 4 pictures and a way to load more... you'll need to adapt that to your purpose